# Using TeamCity's Tomcat to host other applications?

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

Is it wise to use the Tomcat servlet container included with TeamCity to host other WAR applications?

If so, is there a recommended approach do doing so epsecially with respect to upgrading TeamCity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hosting Youtrack.war inside Teamcity's Tomcat without any problems. Upgrades are smooth, only drawback is that Youtrack in unavailable during upgrade.

Comment: cheers for sharing your experience. although it looks like jetbrains don't support this scenario and recommend using a standalone servlet container - http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5306406#5306406